# Cannot build v3.0alpha0-pre with Qt 5 on Ubuntu

Tags: qt-creator, cocos2d-x

I already search but don't found anything helpfull yet.
I just download the v3.0alpha0-pre and see the cocos2dx-qt5.pro, so I open it with my Qt Creator and build, but it failed:

> /cocos2d-x/cocos2dx/platform/qt5/CCApplication.h:67: error: 'ccLanguageType' does not name a type
>   /cocos2d-x/cocos2dx/platform/qt5/CCApplication.h:84: error: 'TargetPlatform' does not name a type

My system info:
Ubuntu 12.10 (old but I think I have all libs/tools needed). 
Qt Creator 2.7.2 Based on Qt 5.1.0 (64 bit).

I'm doing something wrong or this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ubuntu 13.04 or later.